# Scalar Multiple times $n \times n$ Identity Matrix Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics

How to prove
$\det(kA) = k^{n}$ where $A$ is the $n \times n$ Identity Matrix using induction.

I started off using the base case, forming my inductive hypothesis and trying to factor out $k^{n}$ times $k$ for the $(n + 1)$-th case by using the definition of the determinant but I am completely lost on the technicalities and notation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determinant of matrix times a constant.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1215555/determinant-of-matrix-times-a-constant). Note $\det(A) = 1$ where $A$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix.

Answer (score 1):

The rule to calculate the determinant of a matrix by cofactor expansion along the first row:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots& a_{1n}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots \\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \cdots & a_{nn}
\end{vmatrix}$$
$$= (-1)^{1+1}\cdot a_{11}\cdot |A_{11}| + (-1)^{1+2}\cdot a_{12}\cdot |A_{12}| + \cdots + (-1)^{1+n}\cdot a_{1n} \cdot |A_{1n}|$$

where $|A_{ij}|$ is the determinant of the matrix by crossing out the $i$-th row and $j$-th column. For example $|A_{11}| = \text{(crossing out the first row and first column)}=$

$$\begin{vmatrix}
 a_{22} & a_{23} &\cdots & a_{2n}\\
 a_{32} & a_{33} &\cdots & a_{3n}\\
 \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots \\
 a_{n2} & a_{n3}& \cdots & a_{nn}
\end{vmatrix}_{(n-1)\times(n-1)}$$

But now given the matrix:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
k & 0 & \cdots& 0\\
0 &k & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & k
\end{vmatrix}_{n\times n}$$

This make our life a whole lot easier because if you notice in the above formula for the determinant by cofactor expansion along the first row, the coefficients depend on the matrix entries, and in this case $a_{12},...,a_{1n} =0$.

So

$\begin{vmatrix}
k & 0 & \cdots& 0\\
0 &k & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & k
\end{vmatrix}_{n\times n} =$
$ k\cdot \begin{vmatrix}
k & 0 & \cdots& 0\\
0 &k & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & k
\end{vmatrix}_{(n-1)\times (n-1)} =$

$ k^2\cdot \begin{vmatrix}
k & 0 & \cdots& 0\\
0 &k & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & k
\end{vmatrix}_{(n-2)\times (n-2)} =$
$\cdots =k^{n-2}\cdot \begin{vmatrix}
k &0\\
0 & k
\end{vmatrix} = k^{n-2}\cdot (k^2 -0) = k^n$

Basically once you get comfortable with determinants you'll notice that for diagonal matrices (matrices with nonzero entries only in the diagonal, $a_{11},a_{22},...,a_{nn} \not=0$, the rest all zero), the determinant is just the diagonal entries multiplied, in this case they are all $k$ and the matrix is $n\times n$ so there are $n$ diagonal entries, hence $k^n$.