# Determinant change with column multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Given an n x n matrix A, what happens to its determinant when each of its columns are multiplied by its column number?

I am teaching myself linear algebra with Elementary Linear Algebra by Anton and Rorres. I don't understand the new set of operations that are permissible for solving determinants. This problem in particular stumped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a row or column of a n x n matrix $ A$ is multiplied by k, then the determinant of the new matrix $B$ is

$$ det(B)=k \text{ } det(A) $$

The proof of the above property comes from the definition of determinant. You can look it up [Change in determinant when multiplying row of a matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1187395/change-in-determinant-when-multiplying-row-of-a-matrix)

By this property, if each of the columns are multiplied by its column number, then

$$ det(B)= (1 * 2 * 3 *........* n) det(A) $$